# What's the git: URI scheme and is it documented anywhere

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I maintain a VSCode LSP extension and have just gotten a bug report where we receive a `setBreakpoints` request where the path is a `git`-schemed URI that unescaped looks like `git:/<path>?{ "path": "<backslashed-windows-path>", "ref": "~" }`.

I haven't seen this before and I haven't been able to find any documentation on it.

- What does it mean?
- Is there any documentation or description I could be pointed to?
- Is it meaningful for a debug protocol server to receive such a path?

Answer (score 1):

This happens if there is a "TextDocumentContentProvider" registered for a "git" url scheme. This provider serves the contents for those urls and VS Code happily shows the contents in an editor. If the user sets a breakpoint on these "virtual" files, the underlying url is passed to the DAP breakpoint request.

In general a debug adapter (and the underlying debugger) cannot do much with this urls and should return an "unverified response".

Some extensions (e.g. Java) are actually implementing both the content provider and the debug adapter. In this case the contents of individual entries of a jar- or zip file is available via the content provider and the debug adapter understands to set breakpoints in the individual files inside the archive.

Answer (score 1):

VSCode ships with the ["Git" extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/02e8bd149ca3fb68e7f26ebec33f920ba0feef96/extensions/git), which provides a handler for the `git` URL scheme.

I could not find documentation for it, however we can infer some things from the source code. Most interesting is probably the [`fileSystemProvider.ts`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/02e8bd149ca3fb68e7f26ebec33f920ba0feef96/extensions/git/src/fileSystemProvider.ts). It registers a `FileSystemProvider` which is an interface from VSCode to do file operations like open and stat.

The URI parsing is done in [`uri.fromGitUri`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/02e8bd149ca3fb68e7f26ebec33f920ba0feef96/extensions/git/src/uri.ts):

```ts
export interface GitUriParams {
    path: string;
    ref: string;
    submoduleOf?: string;
}

// ...

export function fromGitUri(uri: Uri): GitUriParams {
    return JSON.parse(uri.query);
}
```

We can see that a `git`-Scheme URI consists of:

- a path: from what I can tell, this is used for the window "title" and detection of modifications (change events). This **must** be an absolute path.
- a query **as json**

  - a path: this is used to identify both the repository and the repository-relative path and passed to git
  - a ref (git ref)
  - a submodule: this overrides the repository inferred from the query path???

---

If you want to write an extension that operates with git, it is possible to use the `git` scheme and the Git extension. For example, you can use such a `git:/` URI for diffs. To assemble them, follow the description of the URI components above, e.g.

```ts
URI.from({
  scheme: "git",
  path: "/home/foobar/repo/myfolder/myfile.ts",
  query: JSON.stringify({
    path: "/home/foobar/repo/myfolder/myfile.ts",
    ref: "HEAD"
  })
})
```